# How could Maddy pay the credit card bill for a Hawaiian vacation when she hasn't left her house in 18 years?

Tags: plot-explanation, everything-everything

> **How did Maddy, who hasn’t left her house in 18 years [intend] to pay
>   what must be a humongous credit card bill?**
>
> <sup>[variety.com - Film Review: ‘Everything, Everything’](http://variety.com/author/joe-leydon/)</sup>

During the movie *Everything, Everything*, Maddy applies for her very first credit card, which she then uses to purchase...

- Clothes to replace her previously white-only wardrobe. ([*$50 per outfit*](https://www.walmart.com/cp/womens-clothing-apparel/133162)) = **$250**
- 2 plane tickets from Los Angeles to Hawaii ([*$400 each*](https://www.expedia.com/lp/flights/lax/hnl/los-angeles-to-honolulu)) = **$800**
- 1 weeklong rental car ([*$20/day*](https://www.kayak.com/Cheap-Honolulu-Car-Rentals.28070.cars.ksp)) = **$140**
- A yellow one-piece bathing suit ([*$30*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I147QBW)) = **$30**
- 1 weeklong rental house for her and Olly ([*$100/day*](https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/hawaii)) = **$700**
- Scuba diving tour + equipment ([*$200*](https://www.oahuscubadiving.com/prices/)) = **$200**

**Considering Maddy is trapped at home and has no source of income, is it ever explained how she could pay off her estimated $2,000 credit card bill?**

If not in the movie, is this possibly explained at all in [the original novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything,_Everything_(novel))?

Comment: So what is your question? How could she pay or how could she get credit?

Comment: People often use credit without the ability to repay. It's how the companies stay in business. In this case though it's clearly a **plot device** and not meant to be examined too closely.

Comment: @Paulie_D My question is a little bit of both, but leaning more towards how she could pay the bill afterwards.

Comment: Then my second comment applies. How **doesn't matter** in the context of the film....it's a plot device so she can experience some freedom.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm confused by your statement, "It's how the companies stay in business." It seems as though people not paying would only lose money for the credit card companies, and they stay in business by way of customers who pay late and pay interest. You're a smart man - I've ready your comments - so I'm curious about this! (I know my question is VERY off-topic for this community.)

Comment: @BrettFromLA On finance, see '**[How do credit card companies make profit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/how-do-credit-card-companies-make-profit)?**'